# (write php echo code inside html) inside php code

Tags: php

Before i had below code , so there was no problem.

```
<?php

if(!empty($orderrecords))
    {
      foreach($orderrecords as $k=>$v)
      {    
?>    

<tr>
<td><?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?></td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" id="assigneeid-<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?>" onclick="assignorderids('<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?>')" name="checkassigneeid" class="assigneeid-order" value="<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?>"> </td>
</tr>

<?php

      }
    }
?>
```

Now For some reason i converted that to below code :

```
<?php

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
   {  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
        $output .= ' 
        <tr> 
        <td>'. $row["tracking_id"] .'</td> 
        // 2nd <td> line code ?     
        </tr>  
                 ';  
      }  
    }                                                
?>
```

But how to write **2nd line td code** inside **while** loop . i .e below line :

```
<td><input  type="checkbox" id="assigneeid-<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?>" 
onclick="assignorderids('<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?>')" 
name="checkassigneeid" class="assigneeid-order" 
value="<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?>"> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a "shortcut" (make a variable) to make it more readable:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $tracking_id = $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"] ;

        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'. $row["tracking_id"] .'</td>
            <td>
                <input  
                    type="checkbox" 
                    id="assigneeid-'.$tracking_id.'"
                    onclick="assignorderids(\''.$tracking_id.'\')"
                    name="checkassigneeid" 
                    class="assigneeid-order"
                    value="'.$tracking_id.'">
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168205/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-syscall

Answer (score 0):

```
'<td><input  type="checkbox" id="assigneeid-'.$orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"] .'" onclick="assignorderids('.$orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"].')" 
name="checkassigneeid" class="assigneeid-order" 
value="'.$orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"].'"> 
</td>';
```

You can use this line in your code. It will print expected result.

Answer (score 0):

use `html` in `php` like `echo 'some html'.$php_vars.'some html'.$php_vars;`:

Update your code as:

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {  
        $output .= '
        <tr>
        <td>'. $row["tracking_id"] .'</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="assigneeid-'.$orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"].'" onclick="assignorderids('.$orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"].')" name="checkassigneeid" class="assigneeid-order" value="'.$orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"].'"> </td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
?>
```